# Can we remove trace of data from elastic search query response

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I want to remove the search trace from elastic query response as below:

Elastic query:

```
curl -u username:password elasticURL/elastic_index_name/_search?pretty&filter_path=hits.hits._source,agggregations.**.hits.hits._source
```

Elastic query response:

```
{
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
    {
        "_source": {
          "column1": "data1",
          "column2": "data2",
        }
    },
    {
        "_source": {
          "column1": "data_1",
          "column2": "data_2",
        }
    }]
  },
  "aggregations":{
    "group_by_type": {
        "buckets": [
            "group_by_abc":{
                "buckets":[
                    "group_by_xyz":{
                        "buckets":{
                            "group_doc":{
                                "hits": {
                                    "hits": [
                                        {
                                            "_source" : {
                                                "column1" : "data1",
                                                "column2" : "data2"
                                            }
                                        },
                                            "_source" : {
                                                "column1" : "data_1",
                                                "column2" : "data_2"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

Expected Response:

```
{
    "hits":[{
        "_source": {
          "column1": "data1",
          "column2": "data2"
        }
    },
    {
        "_source": {
          "column1": "data_1",
          "column2": "data_2"
        }
    }],
    "aggregations":[{
        "_source" : {
            "column1" : "data1",
            "column2" : "data2"
        }},
        {"_source" : {
            "column1" : "data_1",
            "column2" : "data_2"
        }}
    ]
}
```

I have found a question related to this:
[AWS API gateway and elastic search get query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54825545/aws-api-gateway-and-elastic-search-get-query)

But, can we achieve this without changing the api getway method response template.

I would like to know, whether it is achievable also or not.

Comment: You could leverage `jq` to "simplify" what you get in the response as suggested in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39741261/4604579

Comment: Thanks @Val and I also got to know, its not achievable through elastic engine.

Comment: No, indeed, you cannot modify what Elastic returns, only filter it.

Comment: Agree, But with filters also, I can't get the expected json output. I found that we can use 'jq' to get the expected response.